# how to put time for this notifications..!

Tags: android, notifications

hey i got this example from https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html
but did little changes i'm not updating i'm putting  50 notification with for function but all 50 comes together how can i make every one appears in a 1 or 5 min
just tried handler didn't work look at my code plz

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AlertReceiver.class);

            final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 100, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
      //      final PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 101, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
         //   final PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 102, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            final AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        //    final AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
       //     final AlarmManager alarmManager2 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES/90, pendingIntent);
       //     alarmManager1.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent1);
        //    alarmManager2.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_FIFTEEN_MINUTES , pendingIntent2);

        }
    });

}
```

AlertReciever.class

```
public class AlertReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {



@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Intent repeating_intent = new Intent(context, Activity12.class);
    //    repeating_intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 100, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("AAA")
            .setOngoing(false)

            .setContentText("BBB");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);


    notificationManager.notify(100, builder.build());


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
                PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, a, repeating_intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                NotificationCompat.Builder builder1 = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setContentIntent(pendingIntent1)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setContentTitle("CCC")
                        .setContentText("DDD")
                        .setOngoing(false)
                        .setAutoCancel(true);

                int numMessages = 0;

                builder1.setContentText("addsadasdadad")
                        .setNumber(++numMessages);

                builder1.setAutoCancel(true);
                NotificationManager notificationManager1 = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                notificationManager1.notify(a, builder1.build());

            }
        }
    }, 1 * 60 * 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code will help you.

```
Handler mHandler=new Handler;
mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 60000); 

Runnable mRunnable=new Runnable()
{
    @Override 
    public void run()
    { 
       // your notification code
       mHnadler.postDelayed(mRunnable ,60000);

    }
}
```

Comment: what should mRunnable i reference ?

Comment: i got problem with override run

Comment: runnable is a interface  used to process your request in mainthread. and in your case request to show notification.

create runnable object in properly. it will not give override issue.

Comment: i did it still have problem with        mHnadler.postDelayed(!!!mRunnable !!!!,60000);
the second mRunnable and this code gives me notificaton every hour singal notifcation or all of them will appears at once ?

Comment: i added same code in the  public void run()
but all the 5 notification comes togheter

Answer (score 0):

// set alaram using this method  (Put Time accroding to need )

```
 public static void setAlarm(Context context, String action, int actionCode, long syncTime)
    {
        AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(action);
        intent.putExtra(ACTION, actionCode);
        PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, actionCode + 1000, intent, 0);
        alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (interval), interval, alarmIntent);
    }
```

//Put intent reciver

```
public class AlarmIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{

    public static final int ACTION_NAME= 101;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        int action = intent.getIntExtra(AlarmUtil.ACTION, 0);
        switch(action)
        {
            case ACTION_XYZ:
//perform action according to need          
 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what should i put here for 5 min + (interval), interval,

Comment: no you put here like SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+5,5 (5 min is interval here )

Comment: i did like u wrote but i can't  call it on the onclicklistener

Comment: problem with parameters

Comment: You can do just put near start time (you can use system time ) another option you create service and call start service onclick()